# unique_ptr in class how to work with them

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I am implementing AVL tree in C++ and using `unique_ptr` for children.

```
struct Node 
{
    const int key;
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left, right;
    Node* parent;
    std::size_t height; ///< for avl tree.
    Node(const int key) : key(key), height(0) {}
};

class AVL
{
    std::unique_ptr<Node> root;
public:
    AVL(int rootKey) : root(std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(rootKey))) {
    }

    void insert(std::unique_ptr<Node> newNode) {
        std::unique_ptr<Node> & node = root;
        Node* parentWeak;
        while(node.get()) {
            parentWeak = node->parent;
            if (node->key == newNode->key)
                throw std::runtime_error("Key already present");
            if (node->key < newNode->key) 
                node = node->right;
            else
                node = node->left;
        }

        auto parent = parentWeak;
        const int key = newNode->key;

        if (parent == nullptr) {
            // there is no root
            root = std::move(newNode);
        } else {
            if (parent->key < newNode->key) {
                assert(NULL == parent->right.get());
                parent->right = std::move(newNode);
            } else {
                assert(NULL == parent->left.get());
                parent->left = std::move(newNode);
            }
        }

        // Now increment the height upto down.
        incrementHeight(key);
        // balance starting from parent upwards untill we find some dislanace in height 
        balance(parent, key); 
    }
};
```

I am getting compiler errors on line `node = node->right;`. Which is right because it can be possible with only `std::move` semantics. but that would be wrong because i want to just iterate over the tree, otherwise it would just remove them from the child-list.

However, i need the `unique_ptr` also, as it would passed in function `balance` as it would modify the pointers and re-balance the tree.

If i use `shared_ptr` it would all work. However, i do not need to share the ownership with others. Or am i misunderstanding ownership ?

Comment: Where is the `parent` member defined?

Comment: `node` should be a pointer.

Comment: @imreal `parent` is raw pointer in `Node`. It got removed it during copy-paste.

Comment: It might be possible (didn't check it), but it does not seem useful to initialize a weak_ptr from a raw pointer. A weak_ptr is meant to point to an object managed by shared_ptr. If it really works, the shared_ptr is a temporary which will end-of-life way too soon (directly after creating the weak_ptr), so locking it will yield a null pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be caused by a lack of understanding how to use `unique_ptr` in real programs, which is related to the concept of *ownership*. If a something *owns* an object, it means, this something is responsible for keeping the object alive as long as this something keeps owning the object, and is responsible to destroy the object as soon as *nothing* owns the object anymore.

Both `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` can be used to *own* objects. The difference, you seem to be aware of, is that an object pointed to by `unique_ptr` can only have a single owner, while there might be multiple `shared_ptr` objects *sharing ownership* of a specific object. If a `unique_ptr` is destroyed or assigned a different value, *by definition* it can destroy the object it previously pointed to, as a `unique_ptr` is the single (unique) owner of an object.

Now you have to think about your tree: You can use `shared_ptr` for everything, which will likely (seems to) work, as objects are kept alive as long as there are references to them. If there really is the `parent` member in `node` which you use in your method but did not declare in the `node` structuer, you would be likely to create reference cycles, though, creating the danger of keeping objects around way too long (or even forever, this is called a memory leak), as `shared_ptr` in C++ is purely reference-counted. Two objects containing `shared_ptr`s pointing to each other keep themselves alive forever, even if no other pointer points to them. It seems like in your `shared_ptr` solution, the `parent` member was a `weak_ptr` which is a sensible way to work around this problem, although possibly not the most efficient one.

You seem to want to improve performance and strictness of your code by using `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` which is commonly accepted as a very good idea, as it forces you to deal with ownership in much greater detail. Your choice that the tree *owns* the root node, and each node *owns* the children is a sound design. You seem to have removed the `parent` pointer, because it can not be a `unique_ptr`, as in that case, a node would be owned by its parents *and* any childrens it might have, violating the constraint that an object pointed to by `unique_ptr` may only have one owner. Also, the `parent` member can not be a `weak_ptr`, as `weak_ptr` can only be used with objects managed by `shared_ptr`. If you want to translate a design from `shared_ptr` to `unique_ptr`, you should consider changing `weak_ptr`s into *raw pointers*. A non-owning pointer to an object managed by `unique_ptr` that detects expiration of that object does not exist (it would not be effienctly implementable with the typical C++ memory management). If you need the property of being able to detect a non-owning pointer to be stale, keep using `shared_ptr`. The overhead for tracking non-owning pointers is almost as big as full shared-ownership semantics, so there is no middle ground in the standard library.

Finally, let's discuss the `insert` method. The `node` variable quite surely is not what you want. You correctly found out (possibly by a compiler error message) that `node` can not be a `unique_ptr`, as that would take away ownership from the tree object. In fact, having this variable *refer to* the root pointer in the tree is the right solution, as you don't want to mess around with ownership at this point, but just want to be able to get a grip on some node. But declaring it as a reference does not fit to the way you want to use it, because *in C++ you can't re-seat a reference*. What you do is you declare `node` to be *just another name* for `this->root`, so if you assign to `node`, you are overwriting your root node pointer. I am sure this is not what you intended. Instead, you want node to refer to a different object than it referred to before, so it needs to be something that references the root node and can be made to refer to something else. In C++, this means you want a pointer (as Jarod42 said in the comment). You have two choices at hand for the loop scanning the position where to insert:

- Use a raw pointer to node instead of a unique_ptr to node. As you don't need ownership, a raw pointer to node is good enough: You can be sure the owning pointer (`this->root`) keeps alive as long a you need it, so there is no danger of the object disappearing.
- Use a raw pointer to unique_ptr to node. This is essentially your approach, fixed to use a pointer instead of a reference.

As you say, you later need the unique_ptr to pass it to the balance function. If the balance function works out as it is now, and needs a unique_ptr argument, the decision is made: Having a copy of the raw pointer in `node` just doesn't do what you want, so you need the pointer-to-unique_ptr.

Comment: It might look dirty to you, but I'm afraid you have to get used to it. Without smart pointers, you sometimes use pointers to pointers, and if the pointer pointed to is a smart pointer, you obviously need a pointer to a smart pointer.

Comment: On the other hand, you are right, pointers to pointers are a complex thing. Maybe you don't need a pointer to unique_ptr, but the parent pointer is enough for your needs, but that discussion extends over the original question. Discussing that would involve the interface of your balancing function for example, and is most likely better suited on codereview than on stackoverflow.